# For Git Hub Pages - Add relative link to .csv file in index.html using d3.csv

Tags: d3.js, github-pages

I have an HTML file using dimple (d3) to create a visualization that runs great when run locally but does not seem to work when I try and host using Github pages. Is there a certain way I need to write the relative link for Github to recognize?

This is the line that I think is not running correctly.

d3.csv("Data and License/FlightData.csv", function (data) {

[Link to repo](https://github.com/andresfmora/andresfmora.github.io/blob/master/index.html)

[Associated Broken Github Page](https://andresfmora.github.io/)

Comment: do not use spaces in directory/file paths that are used as URLs

Answer (score 1):

Flight**d**ata.csv not Flight**D**ata.csv.

```
d3.csv("/Data and License/Flightdata.csv", function (data) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the file path and corrected file name.

What I also ran into was that github pages expects https connections to the D3 and Dimple libraries so once I updated that the github page worked. Thanks for the help.

The new D3/dimple line of code using https.